# Event.watch from ethereum-web3 gets fired infinitely many times

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

I am trying out truffle + web3 + ethereumjs-testrpc. In the app I have the following code:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var meta = MetaCoin.deployed();
  var event = meta.Transfer({}, {fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'}, function (error, result) {
    if (error) {
      console.log("Error: " + error);
    } else {
      console.log(result);
    }
  });
}
```

and I am getting the latest transfer endlessly in console. 
The contract is standard MetaCoin with an event Transfer added. [Here](https://gist.github.com/leitasat/47ae45a0633b4ab0bc833aa631160227) is the full code.

Comment: Please follow up on your question. It looks like you just left it here for others to care about and walked away. To make things worse, there was an answer (by Tim Coulter himself!) that you didn't care to accept, or vote up, or even comment on.

Comment: @DavidAmmouial I don't keep my toy projects around for months, sorry. I had reported the bug on github and apparently it was fixed ( https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/issues/56#issuecomment-205653571 ), but I was not able to test it when the fix arrived, so I did not vote for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it was an issue with the TestRPC. Event-related methods have been updated since, and it's likely a newer version of the TestRPC will solve your issue. Cheers!